# Click/Bind/Unbind - interactive map handlers to work in browsers and on iPad

Tags: jquery, dictionary, click

I've created an image map using the basic map and area tags. I've tested the map and all the areas behave as they are supposed to, so the HTML is definitely correct.

When clicking on an area, the source of the map image is replaced with another.
Naturally, when clicking a second time, the map source should revert to its original state.
It's basically a click/unclick type event and I am trying to use `.bind()` to do the unclicking. For some reason, it doesn't seem to be working.

**The code is as follows:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#area1").click(function(){ 
$("#londonmap").attr('src','images/clickimage.png');
});
$("#area1").unbind("click", function() {
$("#londonmap").attr('src','images/originalimage.png');
});
});
```

I tested this with mouseover/mouseout instead of click and unbind and this works just fine, but of course this is not iPad-friendly. When I attempt this though, only the click works and then the second time I click the area - nothing happens.

I suspect there's something wrong with the way I implemented the .unbind()

Thanks for helping a jQuery noob!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update

- [jsFiddle demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/X6fXq/1/)
- [jsFiddle demo 2 - Generic image swapper](http://jsfiddle.net/X6fXq/2/)
- [jsFiddle demo 3 - Generic image swapper with div clicker](http://jsfiddle.net/X6fXq/3/)
- [jsFiddle demo 4 - Fading](http://jsfiddle.net/X6fXq/4/)

### Original

The `.unbind` event will remove the click event all together. With the current code, once the image has been clicked once, it will remove the click event and be unclickable... forever, sad times! Try toggling the image src like so:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var images = ['http://www.doggyplanet.co.uk/images/new-icon-images/Dog-cartoon.png', 'http://s.thumbs.canstockphoto.com/canstock2134964.jpg'];
    $('#area1').click(function()
    {
        // select the image and determine what the next src will be
        var londonMap = $('#londonmap');
        var newImageSrc = londonMap.attr('src') != images[0] ? images[0] : images[1];

        // re-bind the src attribute
        londonMap.attr('src', newImageSrc);
    });
});​
```

Comment: A second, possibly better, approach is to store an alternate image address in a `data-altsrc` attribute, and switch the two on click using `.attr('src',...)` and `.data('altsrc',...)`. This way, the code is more general and can be reused for any similar image without rewriting.

Comment: @Blazemonger I'm not saying it's not easier, but I did mention I'm a noob so it sort of beats me how and what to replace those two...

Comment: @Blazemonger As requested! The click event is on the image however. :)

Comment: @Blazemonger And there is a more generic one with a button clicker.

Comment: @Richard I know this is off-topic, but seeing ad you've been so helpful - would it be possible to now add a fade effect to the images so that the transition from one another is not so sudden?

Comment: @Richard - sorry to be a pain. The code works fine for the example given, but because the image whose source is being changed is the image that is the base of the <map> tag, I had to use the initial version of your code (without altsrc), as the second image changes according to the various <area> selected. This is kind of what it looks like http://jsfiddle.net/X6fXq/4/